# import existing ssh_authorized_keys into puppet ressource

Tags: ssh, puppet

Is there a way to automatically import all existing ssh keys from /root/.ssh/authorized_keys into puppet? Example:

if I have the following content in /root/.ssh/ssh_authorized_keys:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAakljsehrkjysdfjkhasdkfhskjghg== userA@hostA
ssh-rsa AAAAajklrkljeykljrsyehkrjryekjdkj== userB@hostB
```

I would like to run something like:

```
puppet resource ssh_authorized_key
```

And obtain the following output:

```
ssh_authorized_key {'userA':
    ensure => present,
    key    => 'AAAAakljsehrkjysdfjkhasdkfhskjghg==',
    type   => 'ssh-rsa',
    name   => 'userA@hostA',
    user   => 'root',
}
ssh_authorized_key {'userB':
    ensure => present,
    key    => 'AAAAajklrkljeykljrsyehkrjryekjdkj==',
    type   => 'ssh-rsa',
    name   => 'userB@hostB',
    user   => 'root',
}
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 6):

It may be a bit overkill but you could run [blueprint](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint) and grab the needed sections, or a simple bash script:

```
while read line; do 
    keytype=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}'); 
    keystr=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}'); 
    username=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}');

    echo "ssh_authorized_key {'$(echo $username | awk -F'@' '{print $1}')':"; 
    echo "  ensure => present,"; 
    echo "  key => '$keystr',"; 
    echo "  type => '$keytype',"; 
    echo "  name => '$username',"; 
    echo "  user => '$(whoami)',"; 
    echo "}"; 
done < .ssh/authorized_keys
```

source: http://shtuff.it/article/7/Generate_Puppet_ssh_authorized_keys_resource_from_existing_keys